# How can I call a method on siblings child component or send an event to it in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I need to make siblings child child component kick off a function based on a button click. I am sure some sort of state system would be best but this is a one page prototype ReactJS app. Can I just set some global state and then have the sibling child child bind to it?

How the code is structured

```
<mainComponent>

  <childOne>
    <buttonOne />
    <buttonTwo />
  </childOne>

  <childDose>
    <SocialComponent>
      <SubSocialComponent /> <--- This needs to now buttonOne and buttonTwo click.
    </SocialComponent>
  </childDose>

</mainComponent>
```

Comment: It seems like you can use React.Context APIs to communicate between components and fire events. Have you considered it?

Comment: More about React Context API: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

I think most people will tell you to raise to either raise the state up to a common ancestor and pass down props, use the Context API, or a state management tool like Redux.

I use all these in different areas, but for certain types of "events" I've started to use a tried and true Pub/Sub method, and allows my apps to be much more flexible. I'm not sure how much currency this has in the React community, but I find it extremely useful when components can occur in many places, and other components "care" about what happened.

I use [eventemitter3](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3) because it seems to already be included in most of my react yarn.lock files.

I have what amounts to a global eventemitter object (because it has to be the same object)

```js
import EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3'
window.App.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter()
```

Any component can emit an event at any time:

```js
  emitChanged = () => {
    window.App.eventEmitter.emit('payment-change')
```

And any component can listen to any other event at any time.

```js
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.listen()
  }

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.stopListening()
  }

  listen = () => {
    window.App.eventEmitter.on('credit-card-change', this.resource_manager.refresh )
    window.App.eventEmitter.on('payment-change', this.resource_manager.refresh )
    window.App.eventEmitter.on('handled-old-invoice-response', this.resource_manager.refresh )
  }

  stopListening = () => {
    window.App.eventEmitter.off('credit-card-change', this.resource_manager.refresh )
    window.App.eventEmitter.off('payment-change', this.resource_manager.refresh )
    window.App.eventEmitter.off('handled-old-invoice-response', this.resource_manager.refresh )
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what point is I am missing but doesn't React Context API solves this? And it's included in React itself.